# Is it possible to debug only my own code in Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Silly question but I'm only finding answers online for other browsers. I'm debugging code but it keeps stopping at breakpoints in jquery code and other third party includes.

Is there anyway to debug only my own code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "stopping at breakpoints" Breakpoints are set manually in the Chrome developer tools. If you mean the script halts on error, make sure that the errors are not based on your code. Most libraries are pretty well tested and work fine. If an exception was raised e.g. from inside jQuery, the source of error could be on of your scripts.

Comment: Exactly and you can use the stacktrace to identify how it reached the library, to trackback what caused the error.

Comment: I literally cannot believe this only has 102 views from a year ago. What am I doing wrong in my Javascript! Are we the only two people that ever write bugs?

Answer (score 1):

There is no breakpoint in jQuery code itself but exceptions can happen and your developer tools can stop at exceptions.
To avoid "break on exceptions" you can set the pausing to "Don't stop at exception".

Just click on this icon and switch it to gray.

[image]

It will not stop on exceptions then.

Learn more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-exceptions#pause_on_exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer now has this feature. I think it's a real shame Chrome hasn't introduced this feature yet. It seems like an easy, no brainer to me. If I have a null object somewhere by mistake I want to see instantly which line of code it's on, but Chrome stops in every caught or uncaught exception in library code which is really annoying.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/14/what-s-new-in-f12-with-windows-8-1-update.aspx

It's called 'just my code' and you can mark jquery for instance as being a library and not something you want to see errors in.

> If you are developing Web sites and apps, then you are likely using
> 3rd party libraries like jQuery or Angular, and typically these
> libraries are often minified. We often see developers who are
> debugging their code step into library code, and get buried in the
> depths of that library, before being able to get back to their code to
> debug their issue.
>
> Visual Studio has supported a feature called “Just My Code” (JMC)
> managed languages for a while and with Visual Studio 2012, it is also
> enabled for JavaScript. The idea behind JMC is that we keep the
> debugger in your code, in the code you want to debug and not into code
> you can’t really change.
>
> With this feature now in F12, there are two key things you will see
> when you debug
>
> - You will never ‘step into’ a file (library) that is marked as library
>   code. You can mark a library through the file picker in the debugger
>   (see below), even if you have stepped into the file. Once marked, any
>   step operation will take you to your code.
> - If you enable “break on all
>   exceptions” you will never break on an exception thrown and handled in
>   library code.

[image]